# Algorithm for parsing Syslog Priority Value (PRIVAL)

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, syslog

I'd like to parse the `PRIVAL` info from a syslog entry, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the algorithm needed.

[RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2) says:

> The Priority value is calculated by first multiplying the Facility number by 8 and then adding the numerical value of the Severity.

And with this, here is what I do understand.

```
(X * 8) + y = [known number]
```

so

```
If (X * 8) + Y = 134    
// I happen to know that X = 16 and Y = 6
```

Alternatively

```
If (X * 8) + Y = 78
// What are the values of X and Y?
```

So what would be an appropriate algorithm for parsing this information?

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.graffen.dk/post/Simple-binary-operations-just-confused-me.aspx) about this exact subject a couple of years back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to RFC 5424 the Priority Value is composed from a Facility value in the range 0..23 and a Severity value in the range 0..7.  Given a Priority Value you can extract the Facility and Severity as follows:

```
int priorityValue = 134; // using your example
int facility = priorityValue >> 3;
int severity = priorityValue & 7;
```

This is a simple reversal of the composition operation `priorityValue = facility * 8 + severity` that is used to generate the values you are seeing in the SYSLOG data.  You could also use:

```
int facility = priorityValue / 8;
```

Since we're working with integers this should give you the same results as the bit-shift operation above.

Comment: The bitwise works. I've never looked at bitwise calculations before, I guess I've got some reading to do.

Comment: Still trying to learn the concept behind why this works, but here's a fiddle demonstrating it. http://jsfiddle.net/q6fPA/

Comment: Also, while your second bit `int facility = priorityValue / 8;` works for `int`'s, how would you get the appropriate severity without a bitwise operation?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell alternatively: `var severity = priorityValue % 8;'

Comment: I used the bitwise operations because they are designed specifically for this kind of task.  Bit-shifting an 8, 16, 32 or 64 bit value is a single operation on most CPUs, and is very fast in most cases.  The modulus operation returns the remainder from an integer division (unless it is optimized away by the compiler) which is potentially much slower.  `prival - (facility * 8)` is almost as bad - a multiply and a subtract.  Two slower operations instead of one fast one.

Answer (score 0):

Corey's answer is much more thorough, I prefer divs and mods though (C/C++):

```
const int priority = 134; // using your example
const int facility = priority / 8;
const int severity = priority % 8;
```

Going back the other way:

```
const int priority = (facility * 8) + severity;
```